# Transfer UV maps not working properly

Tags: uv

I having problem transferring UV maps from one object to another. Objects are identical. Please see the image.

1)Object with good UV on the right, selected.

[image]

2)Object that i want transfer UV to. You can see the result after transfer.

[image]

What may be the problem?
[image]

Comment: Do both objects have the same mesh datablock?  You might want to post the .blend file to pasteall.org so people can download and investigate.

Comment: Do you have any modifiers on the objects?

Comment: What do you mean by transfer the UV's to? Why don't you copy the whole object with te good UV's and delete the other one?

Comment: I posted a blend file. There no is modifier Denis. Gladys, i don't know how to put on object in exact place of the second one, if i knew i would do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the two objects are not identical even though they have the same Verts, Edges, Faces but the faces order is different which will cause the transfer to fail ( i guess the order difference is because they where the same object then have been separated or some import / export operation ).

[image]

---

An attempt to place another object at the same location as the bad one:

- select the good object.
- place the cursor at center ( <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> ).
- duplicate and rotate around the **cursor** -72 degrees on the Z axis ( <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> -><kbd>R</kbd>-><kbd>Z</kbd>->***-72*** ).
- place the cursor at the origin of the good object ( not the duplicate ).
- set the origin of the duplicate to the cursor.
- move the duplicate object to the position of the bad object

Comment: Thank you Chebhou. Can this be considered a poor practice to model things in this way? So the seemingly identical objects have a different component order.

Comment: How did you get the face index numbers to show? "2108, 2100, 2109..." That could be useful. I can't seem to find anything about it in Blender's manual though.

Answer (score 3):

Transfer the Object Data from the Active object to the Selected object before you transfer the UV maps.

**Object Mode:** Object > Make Links > Object Data

**Object Mode:** Object > Make Links > Transfer UV Maps

This will retain any vertex groups on the original object if rigging has been set up etc.

This is useful for creating symmetric UV maps.

Duplicate object, delete half of new object, add Mirror modifier, Tick the 'U' under textures in mirror modifier, create UV, apply mirror, transfer object data, transfer UV maps.

- Object Data: An entity in the scene with location, scale, rotation. Used by scenes & groups.

[Blender Manual: Data-Blocks](https://www.blender.org/manual/data_system/data_blocks.html)

Comment: Try link Object Data and transfer uv map works. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

the second object has a view double vertices so you have to remove them. In edit mode select the object, then W --> remove doubles. Then UV unwrap again.

Comment: Unfortunately it did not helped. When i deleted Double verts from object with bad UV, transfer UV option was no longer available. When i delete double verts from both objects and do the transfer, resulting UV's are still not good.