# How Can I Preserve UV Maps for Multiple Objects?

Tags: texturing, uv

I searched for an answer to this question, but I can't find an answer. I have a texture that I'm mapping onto multiple objects. I have it placed exactly where I want it on one face of one object, and now I want to copy those UV mapping coordinates for that face to a similar sized face on another object. The objects are otherwise the same shape. Any ideas?

Comment: see http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/14602/2816

Comment: The above link won't work for different shaped objects. But you can duplicate, separate and join the UV-mapped face in another object. Then you can either snap it in place in 3d to replace the other face or select both faces and snap the UVs in the same spot.

Comment: I think it will be easier for me to just write down the coordinates for the face's UV mapping and then place the other face's mapping at the same coordinates.

Comment: Do objects have the same vertex count ? You could *try* transferring UV maps.

Comment: Yes, just a rectangle shape with the same dimensions. I resolved the issue in a roundabout way, but I'd be interested in knowing if there's a better way, since I could use it in the future.

Comment: The method mentioned here - http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/24136/can-i-transfer-an-already-made-uv-to-another-object. I'm not sure if it fits your needs, because e.g. - http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/32976/transfer-uv-maps-not-working-properly.

Comment: No, that works when the entire mapping is transferred. I only want to transfer a single face, but not necessarily from an identical object.

Answer (score -1):

You can use data transfert.

Let's take an exemple with a sphere and a icosphere.

The sphere is unwrapped. And we want to unwrap the icosphere similarly.

[image]

Place the icosphere at the same position. Select the icosphere and select also the sphere (in this order).

[image: here the sphere is shown wired to see all well]

Now click on "data" from the "data transfer" section of the "tools panel". The choose "UVs".

[image]

You will directly obtain this :
[image]

You can also play with the severall options of the data transfer operator (if needed). Particularly, you can choose the UV map you want (the face you are talking about in your question) as source layer.

[image]
Note that finding the good parameters may take time depending of your models.

Comment: How am I supposed to place the icosphere at the same location?? That's the problem I'm asking about: How to line up the UV maps for a face on two different objects. Tell me how you get two UV maps for two different objects in the UV editor at the same time.

Comment: @AnthonyForwood, can you provide an example of the two objects and faces ?

Comment: Sure... http://www.pasteall.org/blend/42413

Comment: @AnthonyForwood. Thanks. I totally misunderstood what you want to do. Additional questions : is it a simplified version of what you want (for instance not just a quad but a more complex model) ? Do you have to do it a lot of times (not just on two objects) ?

Comment: Yes, that's just a simple version of what I have. I said they're not the same size but that was a typing error that I just fixed. They're identical faces. This isn't important any more, since I only needed to do this a few times, but it might come up again in the future.